# Exchage the location infromation +Game center in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center, gamekit

I want to exchange the current location information of the player between other player of the game through the game center.
I had gone through [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GameKit_Collection/_index.html)

But which class help me to make the transfer of location possible?
Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(void)sendData
{  
NSString *mystring=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"lat=22.810000log=71.477989user=%@",lp.alias];
    int myscore=20;
    NSError *error;
    NSData* data=[mystring dataUsingEncoding: [NSString defaultCStringEncoding] ];
    BOOL success = [match sendDataToAllPlayers:data withDataMode:GKPlayerStateConnected error:&error];
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"Error sending init packet:\n%@",error);
    }
}
```

For sending the data
Where match is the object of GKMatch 
and for receiving the data the following delegate method is used

```
- (void)match:(GKMatch *)theMatch didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromPlayer:(NSString *)playerID {    


    if (match != theMatch) return;
    NSString *string = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
    NSLog(@"Received String : %@",string);

    NSString* str_lat =[[[[string componentsSeparatedByString:@"lat="]objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"log="]objectAtIndex:0];


     NSString* str_long =[[[[string componentsSeparatedByString:@"log="]objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"user="]objectAtIndex:0];

    NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:@"user="];
    NSString *str_username = [[string substringFromIndex:NSMaxRange(range)] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];


    NSLog(@"str_lat%@",str_lat);
    NSLog(@"str_long%@",str_long);

    NSLog(@"str_username--%@",str_username);
}
```